# Could you tell me "the extent to which" is a noun phrase or a clause in this sentence?

Tags: phrases, clauses

I have a sentence in my textbook confusing me. The sentence is: Another influential factor for brokers is the **extent to which** the authority is centralized or decentralized.

My concern is what the role of “**to**” in this sentence is. As you can see, here “extent **to** something” looks like a noun phrase, “**to** which …” is usually a clause. So when the two are linked together “extent **to** which …”, it is a noun phrase or a clause in this sentence?

Please give me some clarification or ideas about it.

In addition, I modify this sentence as “Another influential factor for brokers is the extent **that** the authority is centralized or decentralized." The meaning is the same to or clearer than the original sentence?

Comment: *[the] **extent*** is just [a determiner plus] a noun, and ***the extent to which the authority is centralized or decentralized*** is a  "noun phrase". But *[the] **extent to which*** isn't any kind of recognizable "syntactic unit" - it's just some words that happen to occur consecutively in your cited context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Extent *to* which" refers to approaching something. It's like "*Up to* five people can join this event." which means that any number from one to five people can join, so it's not a single value, but all the values "up to."

So, your suggested edit is not the same as the original sentence, because it considers "extent" as a fixed value.

Comment: Thank you Jan. Do you mean "extent to which" here is a noun phrase rather than a clause?  Because I saw a lot of "to which", "in which" clauses, I think "extent to which" is a clause too.

Comment: @edgar,  I believe that the comment under your question that says that "extent to which" is not any recognizable syntactic unit may be correct. I also don't think it needs to be called anything.